# C# Foreach reading from textboxes in wrong order

Tags: c#, foreach, textbox

So I am trying to load coordinates from textboxes to list of doubles. I already edited their TabIndex so they are in order, but when I try to load the numbers it is reading the textboxes in some weird odrer. 2->4->8->7->5->6->3->1 Can anyone help me with this? The sur_x and sur_y are the names of the lists.

```
    public Boolean Nacitanie_hodnot()
    {
        // premazanie listov a vlozenie prvej hodnoty
        sur_x.Clear();
        sur_y.Clear();
        sur_x.Add(0);
        sur_y.Add(0);

        int i = 1;
        // nacitanie hodnot
        /*Ax = double.Parse(suradnica_Ax.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        Ay = double.Parse(suradnica_Ay.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        Bx = double.Parse(suradnica_Bx.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        By = double.Parse(suradnica_By.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

        Cx = double.Parse(suradnica_Cx.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        Cy = double.Parse(suradnica_Cy.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        Dx = double.Parse(suradnica_Dx.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        Dy = double.Parse(suradnica_Dy.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);*/
        foreach (Control control in suradnice_vrcholov.Controls)
        {
            if ((control is TextBox) && (control.Text == "Zadaj"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            else if ((control is TextBox) && ((i % 2) != 0))
            {
                sur_x.Add(double.Parse(control.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));
                i++;
            }

            else if ((control is TextBox) && ((i % 2) == 0))
            {
                sur_y.Add(double.Parse(control.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));
                i++;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: your loop at line 182 is not correct :)

Comment: Why do you believe that the controls collection is ordered by the tab index? You need to sort them if you want them that way.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. Read this: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245) and [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Don't post images of your code - post a replicable code example that others can use to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to reach:?

```
foreach (Control control in suradnice_vrcholov.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
```

Comment: Alright guys, it was my first post, I am gonna keep that in mind next time I post something. I will let you know if your answers helped asap. Thanks

Comment: This one does not work... Is there any other way to sort them?

Comment: Could you please comment on what exactly not working, the ordering should work, maybe more explicit list of Controls should be ordered.

Comment: The OrderBy is displaying error, gonna post it soon.

Comment: @EduardAbliazimov, have you imported System.Linq namespace (`using System.Linq;`)? `.OrderBy(...)` is a Linq extension method and is only usable/accessible when importing its namespace.

Comment: The updated version works. Thanks man :) Could you also add the firts one in the comments?

Comment: @Matej sure, you are welcome! 
foreach (Control control in suradnice_vrcholov.Controls.OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))